# Veil-E install issue

Tags: kali-linux

I have tried to install this several times, changes sources, and gone through every solution online so far, including the one in this forum and still having issues getting this to install on KALI. Any help is greatly appreciated

```
root@kali:/etc/apt/Veil-Evasion/setup# ./setup.sh 
==========================================================================
 Veil-Evasion (Setup Script) | [Updated]: 2016-02-23
==========================================================================
 [Web]: https://www.veil-framework.com/ | [Twitter]: @VeilFramework
==========================================================================


 [I] Kali Linux "2016.1" x86_64 Detected...


 [?] Are you sure you wish to install Veil-Evasion?

 Continue With Installation? ([y]es/[s]ilent/[N]o): y


 [*] Initializing Package Installation

 [*] Adding x86 Architecture To x86_64 System for Wine
 [*] Installing Wine 32bit and 64bit Binaries
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
 [ERROR] Failed to install Wine... Exit Code: 100.
```